# iOS Playing Video from memorystream

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, streaming, memorystream

My iOS app downloading encrypted mp4 file from server to my document folder.

I'll decrypt mp4 to my Memory and play video from memory.

For security, my app should not make decrypted mp4 file to doc folder.

How can I play Video from memorystream?

I'm trying with FFMpeg..or is there any other solutions?

Can I customize avio_open2() and avformat_open_input()?

Please help me....

Answer (score 2):

Set [AVFormatContext->pb](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.3/structAVFormatContext.html#a1e7324262b6b78522e52064daaa7bc87) to a self-created [AVIOContext](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.3/structAVIOContext.html) that wraps your memory stream. Most important are the [read_packet()](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.3/structAVIOContext.html#a89930f812df15d2d0108f9b65392fc00) and [seek()](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.3/structAVIOContext.html#a0b4f06675c3ea2df5b455bd3334244fe) function callbacks, which your application should implement to do actual packet reading and seeking for the (mp4) demuxer. You can also look at [earlier questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604633/reading-a-file-located-in-memory-with-libavformat) along the same path.