# avformat_alloc_context returns null

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm currently trying to play a video from a stream through FFMPEG. I'm currently stuck however on a particular section: regardless of what I do, `avformat_alloc_context();` seems to return null.

Would anyone perhaps know what might be going on?

I've been referencing the link below:
[Reading a file located in memory with libavformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604633/reading-a-file-located-in-memory-with-libavformat)

Answer (score -1):

1 Call `av_register_all()` fisrt.(Initialize libavformat and register all the muxers, demuxers and protocols)

2 Check code like `avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, file_name, NULL, NULL)` ,did that return not-0.If that,`pFormatCtx` return nil;