# Undefined AVFormatContext duration for custom AVIOContext

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav

The question is why field AVFormatContext::duration is undefined after

```
avformat_open_input
avformat_find_stream_info
```

if used custom AVIOContext like in [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/avio_reading.c) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604633/reading-a-file-located-in-memory-with-libavformat/14528148).

With simple file opening, this field is set. [Example](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/remuxing.c#L75)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I not defined seek function so for std::istream example this should be

```
static int64_t seekFunction(void* opaque, int64_t offset, int whence)
{

auto& stream = *reinterpret_cast<std::istream*>(opaque);

if(whence == AVSEEK_SIZE)
{
    size_t position = stream.tellg();

    stream.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    size_t begin = stream.tellg();

    stream.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t end = stream.tellg();

    stream.seekg(position, std::ios::beg);

    return end - begin;
}

stream.seekg(offset, std::ios::beg);

return stream.tellg();

}
```

And you should also add clear for clear for stream in readFunction in case of eof